# Add intermediate .Net based mediator to VNC client-server connection

Tags: .net, windows, proxy, remote-access, vnc

I am seeking suggestions on a complex problem.

I`ll start with some kind of schema.
If usual VNC client-server connection looks like that:

> [client-web-interface] <===> [VNC-server]

Then i need to make something like that:

```
                                       /=> [VNC-server-1]
[client-web-interface] <===> [Proxy] <===> [VNC-server-2]
                                       ...
                                       \=> [VNC-server-N]
```

(Windows servers, all of them)

So what i need is to add mediator between client and number of VNC servers. Generally VNC servers are in local network and connected to the world using that proxy server only.

Proxy server by itself is not only redirecting connections from client to exact server, it also authorizes client and decides to which server client will be connected. Authorization and server selection is part of .Net based application logic and, lets assume, it is already up and running. 
So what i need more concretely from VNC stack:

- add some intermediate Proxy between client and server (the hardest part). Which, as i understand, would act as VNC server for actual client and, vise versa, would act like client for actual server.
- add some logic to proxy, which would decide to which server connect the client (for now, it can connect them just randomly, so we are not stuck with "how to get actual data from .net application").

I am comletely new to VNC, so excuse me of i made any mistakes.

I would appreciate any ideas.
.Net based solution would be perfect.